# how to change cell borders and add table boder python pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have a problem in changing the cell thickness of a table in PowerPoint Python
this is my code :

```
@staticmethod
    def SubElement(parent, tagname, **kwargs):
        element = OxmlElement(tagname)
        element.attrib.update(kwargs)
        parent.append(element)
        return element

    def _set_cell_border(self, cell, border_color="000000", border_width='0'):
        tc = cell._tc
        tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
        for lines in ['a:lnL', 'a:lnR', 'a:lnT', 'a:lnB']:
            ln = self.SubElement(tcPr, lines, w=border_width, cap='flat', cmpd='sng', algn='ctr')
            solidFill = self.SubElement(ln, 'a:solidFill')
            srgbClr = self.SubElement(solidFill, 'a:srgbClr', val=border_color)
            prstDash = self.SubElement(ln, 'a:prstDash', val='solid')
            round_ = self.SubElement(ln, 'a:round')
            headEnd = self.SubElement(ln, 'a:headEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
            tailEnd = self.SubElement(ln, 'a:tailEnd', type='none', w='med', len='med')
```

But this code does not work
and this is my table :
[image: Figure1]

Comment: You seem to be showing a pie chart and not a table - so I'm confused.

Comment: It might seem that way. But consider a photo or a text that is in a table and I want to remove the border of the table or cell.